# Build Sphinx Documentation on ReadTheDocs

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-sphinx, django-sphinx

There's a way to let readthedocs.org build a sphinx-based documentation for a Django project (hosted on git) that is running on google app engine?

I continue to get this error:

```
Sphinx Standard Error
The Google App Engine SDK could not be found!
```

I created the following requirement file:

```
django
ez_setup
google-appengine
```

But ReadTheDocs fails unpacking google-appengine

```
Downloading/unpacking django (from -r docs/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Running setup.py egg_info for package django

Downloading/unpacking ez-setup (from -r docs/requirements.txt (line 2))
   Downloading ez_setup-0.9.tar.gz
   Running setup.py egg_info for package ez-setup

Downloading/unpacking google-appengine (from -r docs/requirements.txt (line 3))
   Running setup.py egg_info for package google-appengine
   Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
       File  "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/****/envs/latest/build/google-appengine/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
       import ez_setup
   ImportError: No module named ez_setup
   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
   Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/***/envs/latest/build/google-appengine/setup.py", line 2, in <module>

import ez_setup
ImportError: No module named ez_setup
```

Comment: Maybe add google-appengine to the requirements file in your repo that readthedocs use.

Comment: I edited the question and added both the requirement file and the response from RTD

Comment: Is google_appengine a requirement to get your docs compiled (i.e. it is referred directly or indirectly in the modules?)

Comment: well, I'm using the `automodule` functionality...so the doc is compiled directly from the comments in the code

Comment: I'm guessing you're importing the app engine sdk somewhere in your code, and since the SDK files are not packaged in your repo, readthedocs fails when parsing.  You probably want to exclude google-appengine from your docs.

Comment: @dragonx yes that's the reason. And it's for this reason that I added `google-appengine` to the requirements file. The problem is that RTD crash during the unpacking...

Comment: I'd recommend making your own fake google-appengine package that does nothing (ie an empty python file), and use that to appease RTD.

Answer (score 0):

`ez_setup` is not something you'd normally depend on. It was a single `ez_setup.py` file that used to be bundled next to your `setup.py` to help people that don't have `setuptools` (or `distribute`) installed. In your setup.py would be something like:

```
try:
    import setuptools
except Import Error:
    # run ez_setup
```

But you're using virtualenv and you can pretty much count on people having virtualenv/setuptools/distribute nowadays. So you can remove all the `ez_setup` references, especially from your `requirements.txt`.

I think the `ez_setup` module that you're installing is interfering with something in app engine's own `setup.py`.

Comment: I added `ez_zetup` just because RTD can't find it. Sadly, it doesn't work even without `ez_setup` in the requirements file